# Wordpress URL not working?

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules, site-url

I am using Wordpress, I have some URL issue.

My current URL is IP address on server: `http://www.192.10.1.22/states/?q=ohio`

I want URL: `http://www.192.10.1.22/states/ohio`

I used following code in `functions.php` file and it's working in my
local but when I upload in Cpanel then it's now working given me an error
page not found.

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
      add_rewrite_rule(        
            'states/([^/]*)/?',        
            'index.php/states/?q=$1',        
            'top' );
    }

    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

I also update permalink and apache mode_rewrite is also on. So how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `rewrite_rules` works in Wordpress. 
You miss two things.

1. **Match**. It has `$1`, but in reality (take a look to [example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)), you need to work with `$matches`.
2. Your **[Query Var](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars)**. You using `q`, but its not wp native or declared in example code. You can use one of the public ones or declare your [query var](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=query_vars) and logic behind it.
3. If you are **OK** with Regular Expressions and already implemnt first two changes, but it still doesn't work - I would suggest to use [debug bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar) and my plugin [debug bar rewrite rules](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-rewrite-rules)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in the functions.php

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_state_var', 0, 1);
function add_state_var($vars){
    $vars[] = 'state_names';
    return $vars;
}

function custom_rewrite_rule() {
      add_rewrite_rule('^states/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type=page&pagename=states&state_names=$matches[1]','top');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Comment: This will bring to running `flush_rewrite_rules()`every single request.

Comment: Once run flush_rewrite_rules just comment that line.

Comment: Should you add this to code or something?